# Backgammon move notation - Is there an official, rigorous specification?

Tags: backgammon, notation

I have recently become completely obsessed with Backgammon and I would like to learn more about the "Magriel notation" ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backgammon_notation)) used to formally describe a game of BG.

So is there a **definitive**, *formal specification* document for the Magriel notation?

Failing that, is there some online archive of real-world games that have been stored (correctly) in this notation that one could download and examine?

Answer (score 2):

Paul Magriel's notation system originally appeared in his 1976 book *[Backgammon](https://g.co/kgs/cN6oCk)*, and is mostly just a codification of notations systems that existed at the time.
This could be considered the *"official"* specification for the notation, but really it's usage is just customary.

His followup *[An Introduction to Backgammon](https://g.co/kgs/PVbgHh)* also includes the notation, but has an easier to follow explanation as it is targeted at beginners.